# Is there an API to access the Import/Copy Components log files in D2L?

Tags: desire2learn, valence

Using the (g)ui in desire2learn, if you have sufficient permissions you can look at the history of import/copy requests for a target org unit.  Is there a programmatic way to access that history?

We copy lots of items using Valence and the only indications we get are if the job itself failed.  Often a job will succeed, yet some part of the copy failed and we want know that.

Answer (score 0):

A new experimental API route to retrieve the logs for an import job will be released on v10.4.10 of Brightspace in continuous release. The docs for it will be coming very soon, but the route won't be available to clients on platforms older than v10.4.10.